# How to add 1x1 convolution as classification layer to VGG?

Tags: pytorch, vgg-net

I am trying to train a neural network using the first 5 layers of VGG16 as a feature extractor with Imagenet pre-trained weights. These layers contain 5 Max pooling layers which reduce images to 1/32th of original image size. For images with size 640x360, I have activation maps of 20x11 and 512 channels.

I want to classify each activation between 20 classes, taking as input the 512 channels by creating a 1x1 convolution created like this:

```py
# Model definition
class BlockWiseCSRNet(nn.Module):
    """
    Implementation of paper Counting objects by clockwise classification

    Implementation of a method with CRSNet backend
    """

    def __init__(self, load_weights=False, count_levels=10):

        super(BlockWiseCSRNet, self).__init__()
        self.seen = 0
        self.backend_feat = [64, 64, 'M', 128, 128, 'M', 256, 256, 256, 'M', 512, 512, 512, 'M', 512, 512, 512, 'M']
        self.backend = make_layers(self.backend_feat)
        self.count_levels = count_levels

        self.classification = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=count_levels, kernel_size=1),
                nn.Softmax(dim=1)
            )

        if not load_weights:
            mod = models.vgg16(pretrained=True)
            self._initialize_weights()
            # copy weights from VGG pretrained to frontend
            for k, v in self.backend.state_dict().items():
                if 'weight' in k:
                    self.backend.state_dict()[k].data[:] = mod.state_dict()['features.' + k][1].data[:]
                else:
                    self.backend.state_dict()[k].data = mod.state_dict()['features.' + k][1].data

    def freeze_backend(self):
        """
        Freeze backend parameters to make it not trainable
        :return:
        """
        for p in self.backend.parameters():
            p.requires_grad = False

    def unfreeze_classification(self):
        for p in self.classification.parameters():
            p.requires_grad = True

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.backend(x)
        x = self.classification(x)
        return x

    def _initialize_weights(self):
        for m in self.modules():
            if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
                nn.init.normal_(m.weight, std=0.01)
                if m.bias is not None:
                    nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)
            elif isinstance(m, nn.BatchNorm2d):
                nn.init.constant_(m.weight, 1)
                nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)


def make_layers(cfg, in_channels=3, batch_norm=False, dilation=False):
    if dilation:
        d_rate = 2
    else:
        d_rate = 1
    layers = []
    for v in cfg:
        if v == 'M':
            layers += [nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)]
        else:
            conv2d = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, v, kernel_size=3, padding=d_rate, dilation=d_rate)
            if batch_norm:
                layers += [conv2d, nn.BatchNorm2d(v), nn.ReLU(inplace=True)]
            else:
                layers += [conv2d, nn.ReLU(inplace=True)]
            in_channels = v
    return nn.Sequential(*layers)


### Relevant train loop

model = BlockWiseCSRNet(count_levels=20)
criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(filter(lambda x: x.requires_grad, model.parameters()), args.learning_rate)

# train loop step
def train_step(epoch, device, data_loader, model, criterion, optimizer):
    print('train step!')
    running_loss = 0.0

    # set model to train mode
    model.train()
    # only train classification layers, keep weights of backend
    model.freeze_backend()
    model.unfreeze_classification()

    for mini_batch, (batch, labels, filenames) in enumerate(data_loader):
        # Transfer to GPU
        batch = batch.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)

        # zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # process batch
        outputs = model(batch)

        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        a = list(model.classification.parameters())[0].clone()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        b = list(model.classification.parameters())[0].clone()
        print('weights updated? {}'.format(not torch.equal(a.data, b.data)))

        #print(torch.sum(model.classification[0].weight.sum()))

        # print statistics every print_stats_steps mini-batches
        running_loss += loss.item()

    print('[{}] total train loss: {}'.format(epoch, running_loss))
```

This solution is able to process images and give output activations with proper sizes.

However, I am not able to train the network. I am using CrossEntropyLoss and Adam optimizer but output maps are always constant (even after multiple training iterations)

```py
# batch is an image

batch.shape -> torch.Size([1, 3, 360, 640])

output = model(batch)

output.shape -> torch.Size([1, 20, 11, 20])


criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), args.learning_rate)


_, predicted_class_map = torch.max(output, dim=1)

# predicted class map is always 0
```

I have tried several learning rates and configurations, but the predicted class map is always 0. I debugged weight updating and updates are always 0 (before and after optimizer step weights are equal)

What I am doing wrong? I am not sure if the problem is at the architecture or in the training loop (which I took from PyTorch tutorials)

EDIT: After inspecting the content of net output, I think that the problem is that all channels in output have the same values for all image. So:

```py
all_means = [ outputs[0, t, :, :].mean().item() for t in range(0, outputs.shape[1])]
```

has a vector with all positions equal.

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't output shape be 2D? (batch_size, num_classes)?

Comment: output shape is already 2d, [1, 20, 11, 20], with batch size=1, num classes=20 and shape 11x20

Comment: What is 11 x 20 ?

Comment: 11x20 is the final activation map dimensions (height 20, width 11)

Comment: Post some more of your code. It's difficult to see what you are trying to achieve and where it might have gone wrong.